# Same activity for multiple feed

Tags: getstream-io

I am trying to understand how to create an activity for multiple feeds and mantain the uniqueness of the activity.

Context: in my App users can create text posts (activity) with a category associated. You can follow users (feed) but you can also follow categories (another feed).

So I'm a little confused about how to proceed when I create the activity for the post.

For example, user "Peter" creates a post under the category "History", so users that follow "Peter" should see the post but also users that follow "History" should see the same post.

How can I archieve this functionality?

EDIT: I could archieve this functionality using the "To" field referencing to the "Category" feed.

Answer (score 2):

Activities are given their uniqueness via `ForeignID` and `Time`. Thus, when you add your text post(activity), make sure to provide a unique `ForeignID` and `Time`. Then, you can add the same activity to other feeds and it will remain unique. For a more detailed insight, check out our docs on this specific topic: https://getstream.io/docs/#uniqueness

Comment: Thanks Ion, I tried adding 2 activities with the same ForeignId and Time but a duplicated exception rised. I'm using the python stream API by the way.